# Rep for edits: maxes out at 1000pts, but what about deleted posts?

Tags: discussion

The rep for edits maxes out at 500 posts (1000 rep). But whenever a user deletes a post you lose the rep gained for it. However, from what I can tell this doesn't come off your 1000 rep total max.

Thus it seems like it would be possible to edit 500++ posts, have them all deleted, and end up with no rep at all from edits, despite all the effort put in.

Is this true and if it is, does it not seem like something is more that a little wrong here?

Comment: Not at all. If you edit something that then gets removed... What good have you done the site, the community?

Comment: @Patrice Me personally? You wouldn't believe me if I told you.

Comment: I truly dont get what you are saying. In any case, rep is a measure of your contributions.... If the posts you edit get deleted.... Your edits bring nothing to Stack. So yes, the drop in rep is warranted.

Comment: See "What are the criteria from deletion?" within [the FAQ answer on deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/133299). Answers are only deleted in unusual circumstances; most answers are never deleted, and most answers that are deleted are not the kind of thing anyone would've bothered suggesting an edit for. So even if this is true, "more than a little wrong" is an exaggeration - unless you're deliberately seeking out deletion-worthy posts to suggest edits for, you'll at most miss out on rep from a handful of edits out of those 500.

Comment: @Jefromi That's pretty much the answer I was looking for. I noticed a few times getting the -2 for a deleted post I'd edited, but never noticed the number coming off the total number of edited posts.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding the question or the accepted answer only answers part of your question. I thought you were asking whether or not losing some of the 1000 rep due to deleted posts meant you were back below the cap or not.

Comment: @BSMP Like, whether Copy Editor would get taken away? I didn't think about that, but it's an interesting point. Weirdly, I don't think I'd mind, but it would be interesting to know. I quite like editing stuff sometimes and it's nice to feel you're getting rewarded for it.

Comment: No, not the badge. I thought you were wondering if your 501st edit could get you rep if you lost some due to your 473rd edit got deleted.

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, that was part of what I wanted to know. I think you're right on this one.

Answer (score 13):

The system doesn't cap at 500 posts, it caps at 1,000 reputation. The number of posts is completely irrelevant, as it's possible that your reputation could have been capped on a day with edits, which wouldn't have gained you reputation.

As far as deleted posts: yes, you do lose the reputation if the post is later deleted, for good reason as outlined in the comments and other answer. But you also re-earn the reputation from other suggested edits. When deletions occur, your entire reputation history gets recalculated as if the reputation never existed.

- If you didn't have any other edits to compensate for the deletion, then you can simply suggest another edit to gain the 2 reputation again.
- If you had other approved edits which didn't give you reputation due to the 1,000 cap, the one that gets deleted will "cease to exist" and the next edit that didn't give you anything will now count for +2 for a net gain/loss of 0 due to the deletion. **This is where it gets a little confusing.**

  Due to the way the reputation history works, the deleted post will still show a gain of +2 when the edit was approved. Now, the next eligible edit will *also* show a gain of +2 at the time that edit was approved, way back in your history, *not on the day the post was deleted*. But the day the post was deleted will also generate a -2 event for the deletion, which counters the +2 for the original edit way back in your history. The confusing part is even though some other edit in your history is now counting for an additional +2, it doesn't notify you of this change on the day it occurs.

  So you end up with a deleted post that has a +2 event and a subsequent -2 event cancelling it out, and some other post that now has a +2 instead of a 0.

Answer (score 7):

I feel like Patrice [got this one right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325979/rep-for-edits-maxes-out-at-1000pts-but-what-about-deleted-posts#comment356239_325979)...

> ...If the posts you edit get deleted.... Your edits bring nothing to Stack. So yes, the drop in rep is warranted.

...but let's explore this a bit.  There are [well-defined criterion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) in which content can be [soft] deleted, and in the event that it *is*, we can rationalize why it implies the question or answer wasn't worth keeping around anyway.

> The system will automatically delete any post flagged six times as offensive or spam.

I find this to be self explanatory but I included it here anyway.  Don't edit spam.  Don't edit offensive content.  Let it be nuked.

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days.

This implies that, after one has edited the question, the question score has not improved to zero or positive, and no one has bothered to answer it in that period of time.

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

This implies that, after one has edited the question, the question simply didn't gain that much attention to it, or didn't get enough requests for clarification (or comments, as it were) in a **year**.  I'm not convinced that this is a common occurrence, but if it is, it implies that this question was outright *ignored*, even *after* one edited it.

> The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.

There are reasons accounts are deleted, as this implies some form of abuse or some other malicious play going on.  Net result is that we don't benefit from their question or answer being on the site anymore.

> Answers with zero or negative score that receive six recommend deletion reviews in the low-quality-posts review queue are automatically deleted “in review”.

Reviewers thought that, even after one had edited the answer, that it still was more fit to be deleted than it was to be kept around.  There are two sides to this:  one shouldn't be trying to polish turds, and even if it *wasn't*, their edit wasn't enough to overcome the reviewer's opinion of the answer's quality.

---

Above all, though, it's 2 reputation.  You get more from an upvoted question, or the same amount if you accept an answer on your question.  Those upvotes are somewhat less vulnerable to the same rules on deletion, as you [keep rep on posts with a score of 3+ and have been on the site for 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/175248).  There's also a very good chance that the question you're looking at is safe from any of the automatic deletion clauses I've outlined above.

If you're looking to gain a lot of rep, then asking good questions and giving good answers is still, by far, the best way to go about it.